# getting this error 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, seaborn

```
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.countplot(x='issue_year',data='df')
```

this is the output of `df['issue_year'].value_counts()`

```
2015    403697
2014    227865
2013    131678
2012     53035
2011     21636
2010     11529
2009      4716
2008      1562
2007       251
Freq: A-DEC, Name: issue_year, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
sns.countplot(x='issue_year',data='df')
```

should be changed to

```
sns.countplot(x='issue_year',data=df)
```

data parameter should be DataFrame object.